# Subtracting two DateTime objects in c++/cli

Tags: datetime, c++-cli

```
System::DateTime ^now = System::DateTime::Now;
System::DateTime ^now2 = System::DateTime::Now;
System::TimeSpan ^span = now->Subtract(now2);
```

The above code gets the compiler error:

```
test.cpp(104) : error C2664: 'System::TimeSpan System::DateTime::Subtract(System::DateTime)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::DateTime ^' to 'System::DateTime'  
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available, or  
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

now and now2 are c++/cli handles, but the method expects the actual object. What is the correct way of invoking the method from c++/cli?

Comment: DateTime::Now is a value type, and Subtract returns a value type.

Comment: Don't write any C++/CLI code until you thoroughly understand the difference between reference and value types.  Any half-decent book about .NET will explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` and `TimeSpan` are value types.

```
System::DateTime now = System::DateTime::Now; 
System::DateTime now2 = System::DateTime::Now; 
System::TimeSpan span = now.Subtract(now2);
```

Comment: I guess more correct: ```System::TimeSpan span = now2.Subtract(now);```

Answer (score 0):

```
System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch^ stopwatch = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch();
stopwatch->Start();
// code
stopwatch->Stop();
// stopwatch->Elapsed
```